# Ideal education system for sustainable life

Tags: education

I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask this kind of question. Sorry if it is misleading.

So, what kind of education system would help to promote sustainable development?

My points now

**Reorganized formal education**

- Initiative: more child-to-child approach programmes (child mentoring) and eradicating stereotypes (e.g. gender or racial) by creating media that includes people of different background.
- Implication: it can reach wider base and syllabus catered towards innovation itself and can reduce social inequalities.

**Education that involves application of natural renewable resources as basis**

- Initiative: increase the use of renewable resources through technology (e.g. solar, wind turbines to power cities and factories) which will enhance the workforce in renewable energy industry.
- Implication:it can affect a large number of population and also can affect the environmental aspect which can contribute to a more sustainable world.

**Education that is free for all**

- Initiative: free education focused on primary education (funded by government taxes) and workshop (funded by charity funds)
- Implication: will eradicate the gaps of poverty and give the poor the chance of better education

**Education that involves decision making process**

- Initiative: activities that involve decision-making process such as summer camp, experiments and tour are being featured in education
- Implication: this will enhance the thinking skills of decision-making process of young minds.

I'm also asking if my points are straying off from original question,which is education that aims a more sustainable development.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! I've taken the liberty to revise your question a bit for better readability.
I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I think all education systems can promote sustainable development IF they give attention to it. Perhaps you mean which education system would be most effective?

Comment: @THelper  thanks! :) the question above is based on my understanding(which can be sometimes misleading),so this is the original question: We live in a world with many complex problems, both local and global. What kind of education and learning would help us address these challenges and create a sustainable world and a better life for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that basics of ethics and consciousness come from parents, that said:

1. I feel you are almost describing the [Waldorf system](http://waldorfwatch.com/) (also known as [Steiner Education)](http://www.inhabitots.com/why-waldorf-education-is-a-great-choice-for-environmentally-conscious-parents/) and here's even [more info](http://www.waldorfanswers.org/Waldorf.htm)... you can find lots in internet and almost any city may have already such a School. Maybe your point about free education won't be solved, but could be if we push governments to install Waldorf schools too.
2. I also believe the points established by the [Venus Project](https://www.thevenusproject.com/) about [education](https://www.thevenusproject.com/faq/what-can-you-tell-us-about-the-venus-projects-approach-to-education/) might be interesting for your focus on how to educate kids. You should check out the live's story of it's creator [Jacque Fresco](https://www.thevenusproject.com/the-venus-project/jacque-fresco/) that is included in the [documentary of the project](https://www.thevenusproject.com/the-venus-project/jacque-fresco/).

Answer (score 0):

My point was that [any system suffices](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOfBv82dxdiDRFabTUOYrxcUObLVjJ8TL_a11Ph_WwI/pub). It just needs to make it clear that all you learn should not end at your job.

Comment: Do you mean lifelong learning?

Comment: I mean that school teaches you to optimize your (job) activities, learn how to simplify mathematical expression, optimize efficiency of physical processes, eliminate unnecessary prcesses. You optimize your production processes. You earn money for saving the nature. How do you spend the money? You spend them to kill the nature the way you like. You need to build the house and gasoline for you car. Yet suburbs is the root of evil. I was born in USSR where state payed people for developing efficient vertical public infrastructure. You design public system and spend money to buy a car!